# Need to create Seq[String,String] from a result set

Tags: scala

I have tried to return collection object Seq[String,String]  from a function but its not worked. here is my method,Please help me to resolve this

```
def findAllBrandsseq:Seq[String,String] ={
              val brands =Seq[String,String]()


                 val conn = DB.getConnection()
                 try {
                    val stmt = conn.createStatement
                    val rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from m_brand")
                    while (rs.next()) {

                      brands:+(rs.getString("idbrand"),rs.getString("brandName"))
                    }
                } finally {
                    conn.close()
                }
                return brands
 }
```

It gives following compile errors

> Read from stdout:
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\Project_VendorM6\app\models\Brand.scala:49: wrong
>   number of type arguments for Seq, should be 1
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\Project_VendorM6\app\models\Brand.scala:49: wrong
>   number of type arguments for Seq, should be 1 Read from stdout: def
>   findAllBrandsseq:Seq[String,String] ={
>                def findAllBrandsseq:Seq[String,String] ={ Read from stdout: ^
>                                     ^ Read from stdout:
>
> D:\PROJECTS\test\Project_VendorM6\app\models\Brand.scala:50: wrong
>
> > number of type parameters for method apply: [A](elems: A*)Seq[A] in
> >     class GenericCompanion
> >     D:\PROJECTS\test\Project_VendorM6\app\models\Brand.scala:50: wrong
> >     number of type parameters for method apply: [A](elems: A*)Seq[A] in
> >     class GenericCompanion Read from stdout: val brands
> >     =SeqString,String
> >                   val brands =SeqString,String Read from stdout: ^

Comment: I think what you want is `Seq[(String, String)]`. A Seq of a tuple of String and String

Comment: I did the change as ** val brands =Seq[(String,String)] ** but its not worked. got error  `missing arguments for method apply in class GenericCompanion`

Comment: `Seq[(String, String)]` is the type, of course you are not allowed to drop the parens when you want to create a new Seq. Use `val brands = Seq[(String, String)]()`

Comment: its worked with no compile errors,but seq has no values. In Database there are two values.

Comment: `Seq` is an immutable data-structure. You do not change the contents of `brands` using `:+`.

Comment: so is there any suggestion to return seq with set of data? for above problem

Comment: Use `var brands` and `brands = brands :+ (....)`. But really, think! You've had some good answers, but you don't seem to be considering what they mean, or debugging the code yourself (it would be easy for you to demonstrate `brands` wasn't changing in the loop, for instance).

Comment: Also, you're writing Java in Scala. Consider using one of the various DB access libraries instead? (Slick, etc).

Comment: A `scala.collections.mutable.Buffer[(String,String)]` instead of the `Seq[(String,String)]` may be more suitable for what you are trying to do. In such case, use `+=` instead of `:+`

Comment: By the way, don't get discouraged by comments like "you are writing Java in Scala". That's the way many of us started, and a valid way to gradually learn more.

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo I`m new in scala. just one month,So I`m trying with these with experiments.

Comment: Actually I need to get Seq[(String,String)] for set as options of select tag
   `@select(productSearchForm("probrand"),options=Brand.findAllBrandsseq(),'_label -> "Brand", '_default -> "-- Choose a brand --",'_showConstraints -> false)`